# How to ignore filtering on selected column - equivalent of Power BI's Calculate( [] ; All( [] ))

Tags: tableau-desktop

I would like to create a measure [Ultimate case count] that would disregard any filtered out values on the diemension ReasonID.

But still be sesitive to othere filteres (FInancialName and ImportDate). I Have been trying with FIXED and EXCLUDE but can't get it to work...

Measure [CaseCount] is just a sum() and diff is [Ultimate case count] - [CaseCount]

[image: Tableau screen]

Comment: You are using [Reason ID] as a *context filter* (shown in grey), which means that filter will be applied early in advance of other filters and calculations. While [FinancialName] and [ImportDate] are not *in the context*, which means they will be applied later in the order of operations.